# Transmission-daemon startup script

Tags: raspbian

I tried to delay the startup of transmission-daemon by changing the  /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon to use "sleep 600" in the beginning. But it is still starting right after raspberry is turned on.

Does anyone have an idea?

Ps: I need to delay the startup to avoid "no data found" and wait the mount of my USB HD.

Reference: [How do I delay transmission-daemon startup until all shares are mounted?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27578/how-do-i-delay-transmission-daemon-startup-until-all-shares-are-mounted)

Comment: Recently, we have had this problem and we solve it by adding a USB hub to make a delay for the hub after each startup of RPi. If you want to solve it by hardware, I'll add an answer, though.

Comment: I have an idea. The reference you have used is nearly 5 years old and really outdated. Many important things have changed, mainly using of **systemd** instead of **SysV init** with scripts in `/etc/init.d/`. Please edit the question and paste the output of this command into it: `systemctl status transmission-daemon.service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy solution.

Since it is being started as service, it is getting the parameters from /lib/systemd/system/transmission.service
So, I changed this file adding the sleep 10. It can be even better using RequiresMountsFor parameter

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/transmission.service
```

Add following under [Service] section:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
```

Run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Reference for better solution:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441894/wait-to-start-transmission-daemon-until-after-usb-drive-has-mounted